# getEntities return empty array for all methods

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I tried to get all contacts, emails, phones to show in side pane but all list returns empty arrays, any tips for this please

Comment: Can you please mention on which client (Windows/Mac/OWA) are you trying this and build version.

Comment: Also keep in mind that contacts/emails/phones (as well as other types) from getEntities are extracted from the message body. These values are available only if they can be extracted from the message body. What is the scenario? Would using the recipient (To/Cc) APIs work?

Comment: actually i used web client for test on chrome with my hotmail email, api return empty for all arrays. for work around i used rest api

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT i try to get all related contacts or emails list, now i used rest API to get them and it works, but still need to know why it return empty list 4ever

Comment: getEntities are for information extracted from the message body (for example if the email body has "please email me at user@contoso.com"). If the email/contact is not in the message body, getEntities would not return them. Even then there are limitations in what can be extracted. To actually get the recipient list you can use JS API Office.context.mailbox.item.to/cc. If that's not sufficient, using REST API as you are doing is an alternative. We would also like to learn more about your scenario to see if there's an alternative or if the JS API can be improved.